# PyQt5: How to flip QGraphicsItem parent item only

Tags: pyqt5, parent-child, transformation, qgraphicsitem

I am trying to perform flipping on a `QGraphicsItem` that has *child* and *grandchild* `QGraphicsItem`.

The original item looks like this:

[image: original]

(The blue rectangle and text are *child* and the number inside it is *grandchild*

I apply the following transformation to the parent item:

```
parentItem.setTransformOriginPoint(parentItem.boundingRect().center())
parentItem.setTransform(QTransform.fromScale(-1, 1))
```

Result after flipping parent item:

[image: parent_flipped]

Since I want to reflip the text and number to be readable, I attempt to re-flip them after the parent's transformation as followed:

```
# For the child text
child.setTransformOriginPoint(child.boundingRect().center())
child.setTransform(QTransform.fromScale(-1, 1), True)
...

# For the grandchild number
grandchild.setTransformOriginPoint(grandchild.boundingRect().center())
grandchild.setTransform(QTransform.fromScale(-1, 1), True)
```

Here is the result after re-flipped the child and grandchild item:

[image: child_grandchild_reflipped].

It seems that the *translation* is not correct. Can someone advice?

Thanks!

Minimal reproducible example below:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class ParentItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, pos, name, parent=None):
        w, h = 550, 220
        super().__init__(-w/2, -h/2, w, h)
        self.setPos(pos)

        self.name = ChildText(self.boundingRect().topLeft() - QPointF(0, 100), f">NAME{name}", self)
        self.value = ChildText(self.boundingRect().topLeft()- QPointF(0, 50), f">VALUE_{name}", self)

        self.ChildPad1 = ChildPad(QPointF(-150, 0), "1", self)
        self.ChildPad2 = ChildPad(QPointF(+150, 0), "2", self)

        self.color = QColor(192, 192, 192)
        self.setPen(QPen(self.color, 5))

        self.setFlag(self.ItemIsMovable, True)
    def flipParent(self):
        self.setTransformOriginPoint(self.boundingRect().center())
        self.setTransform(QTransform.fromScale(-1, 1))
    
    def reflipChilds(self):
        # Child Texts
        self.name.setTransformOriginPoint(self.name.boundingRect().center())
        self.name.setTransform(QTransform.fromScale(-1, 1))

        self.value.setTransformOriginPoint(self.value.boundingRect().center())
        self.value.setTransform(QTransform.fromScale(-1, 1))

        # GrandChild Numbers
        for child in self.childItems():
            if isinstance(child, ChildPad):
                child.Number.setTransformOriginPoint(child.Number.boundingRect().center())
                child.Number.setTransform(QTransform.fromScale(-1, 1))

class ChildText(QGraphicsTextItem):
    def __init__(self, pos, text=">Text", parent=None): 
        super().__init__(parent) 
        self.setPos(pos)

        self.parent = parent
        self.text = text
        self.color = QColor(255, 0, 0)
        
        self.setDefaultTextColor(self.color)      
        self.setFlag(self.ItemIsMovable, True)
        
        f = QFont()
        f.setPointSizeF(min(self.parent.boundingRect().width()/8, self.parent.boundingRect().height()/8))
        self.setFont(f)
        self.setHtml(f"<p><center>{self.text}</center></p>")

class ChildPad(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, pos, pinNumber, parent=None):
        w, h = 200, 100 
        super().__init__(-w/2, -h/2, w, h, parent)  
        self.setPos(pos)

        self.parent = parent
        self.color = QColor(255, 0, 0)

        self.setPen(QPen(self.color, Qt.MiterJoin, 1))
        self.setBrush(QBrush(self.color))

        self.Number = GrandChildNumber(pinNumber, self)

class GrandChildNumber(QGraphicsTextItem):
    def __init__(self, pinNumber, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.color = QColor(32, 32, 32)

        self.setHtml(f"{pinNumber}")
        self.moveToParentCenter()
    
    def moveToParentCenter(self):
            f = QFont()
            f.setPointSizeF(min(self.parent.boundingRect().width()/4, self.parent.boundingRect().height()/4))    
            self.setFont(f)
            rect = self.boundingRect()
            rect.moveCenter(self.parent.boundingRect().center())
            self.setPos(rect.topLeft())
            self.adjustSize()

def main():
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    scene = QGraphicsScene()

    # No Transformation applied
    originalItem = ParentItem(QPointF(300, 100), "ORIGINAL", scene)
    scene.addItem(originalItem)

    # Flipped the whole parent item
    flipParentItem = ParentItem(QPointF(300, 500), "FLIPP_PARENT", scene)
    flipParentItem.flipParent()
    scene.addItem(flipParentItem)

    # Flipped the whole parent item, then reflip the Text and Number
    reflipChildItem = ParentItem(QPointF(300, 900), "REFLIP_CHILDS", scene)
    flipParentItem.flipParent()
    reflipChildItem.reflipChilds()
    scene.addItem(reflipChildItem) 

    view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene)
    view.setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante I updated a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ignore transformations, you should use the [`ItemIgnoresTransformations`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum) flag.

Then, be aware that `setTransformation()` doesn't apply the transformation "on top" of the existing one, but completely sets a *new* transformation on the item (transforms inherited from the parent are not considered).

A proper `flip()` function should *toggle* the transformation, so it must consider the *current* [`transform()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#transform) and flip it.

Now, the problem with text items is that they *always* use the origin point as the top left of their contents. While the basic repositioning might work for generic usage, it will not whenever *any* parent has a transformation.

The problem you're seeing is because you are just mapping the position based on the parent, but since the parent is "flipped", the top left corner of the resulting rect is on the opposite side (relative to the center) in parent coordinates.

To properly get the *actual* position relative to the parent, you must always use the cumulative transformations, which means *map* coordinates to the scene and map them back to the parent.

In order to make the code simpler to understand, I moved the repositioning function to the parent of the text item.

```py
class ParentItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    # ...
    def flip(self):
        self.setTransformOriginPoint(self.boundingRect().center())
        self.setTransform(self.transform().scale(-1, 1))

        for child in self.childItems():
            if isinstance(child, ChildPad):
                child.updateNumber()


class ChildPad(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, pos, pinNumber, parent=None):
        w, h = 200, 100 
        super().__init__(-w/2, -h/2, w, h, parent)  
        self.setPos(pos)

        self.parent = parent
        self.color = QColor(255, 0, 0)

        self.setPen(QPen(self.color, Qt.MiterJoin, 1))
        self.setBrush(QBrush(self.color))

        self.number = GrandChildNumber(pinNumber, self)
        self.updateNumber()

    def updateNumber(self):
        br = self.boundingRect()
        f = QFont()
        f.setPointSizeF(min(br.width() / 4, br.height() / 4))    
        self.number.setFont(f)

        # get the "visual" rect of the parent in scene coordinates
        parentRect = self.mapToScene(br).boundingRect()
        rect = self.number.boundingRect()
        rect.moveCenter(parentRect.center())
        # map the new rect position *from* the scene in local coordinates
        topLeft = self.mapFromScene(rect.topLeft())
        self.number.setPos(topLeft)


class GrandChildNumber(QGraphicsTextItem):
    def __init__(self, pinNumber, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.setFlag(self.ItemIgnoresTransformations)

        self.color = QColor(32, 32, 32)

        self.setHtml(str(pinNumber))
```

Comment: Very well explained! You are correct that I do not have my item positioning properly. This is the main issue I have. Understood now, thank you!